# Query to find how many students signed out

Tags: sql, t-sql

I need to write a query to find out how many students signed out after 1st period. We don't store a record if the student was present so I can't say if the student was present 1st period and has 6 absence records (we have 7 period days). All I have is the info in the schema below. I ahve a query that I wrote but its not working. Need some help on where to go from here.

Thanks

[image]

```
    Select student_id, Count(*) AS #ofPerAbsent

    From Attend_Student_Detail

    where School_Year='1112' and School_Number='0031'
    and Absent_Date='2012-04-13' and Absent_Code IN ('ABU','ABX')



    Group by Student_ID

    Having count(*)<=6

ORDER BY #ofPerAbsent desc
```

Comment: I'm guessing your abu and abx are unexcused and excused absences?

Comment: If they sign out, does absent_period reflect the period at which they signed out? Or is that the number of the period that they missed? You might be able to key off of that field if either of those are the case.

Answer (score 0):

So your criteria for determining a student signed out after 1st period is having an Absent_Code or 'ABU' or 'ABX' ?

If that assumption is correct, then you can query as follows to get count of students per day that fit that criteria...

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(Student_ID))
FROM Attend_Student_Detail
WHERE Absent_Code IN ('ABU','ABX')
GROUP BY Absent_Date
```

You can further filter to specific dates in the WHERE clause if you'd like.

Your schema doesn't make much sense to me by the way; so if the above is not what you're looking for, can you please explain your schema a bit more and I'm sure I can help.

Answer (score 0):

from what i can gather you will want to count all the absences minus the count of absences after the first period, so i think something like this should work.

```
SELECT 
  A.student_id, 
  (Count(A.student_id) - B.absences_after) as absences     
FROM 
  attend_student_detail as A
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT 
    Z.student_id,
    Count(Z.student_id) as absences_after
  FROM
    attend_student_detail as Z
  WHERE school_year='1112' AND school_number='0031'
    AND absent_date='2012-04-13' AND absent_code IN ('ABU','ABX')
    AND absent_period <> "period one"
  GROUP BY Z.student_id
) as B
ON B.student_id = A.student_id
GROUP BY A.student_id;
```